# python-selenium on aws lambda throws error when switch_back_to.default_content and try to select element

Tags: python-2.7, iframe, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

python-selenium using phantomjs used to open an iFrame inside the page, then after switching back to the default content(`driver.switch_to.default_content()`) does not work.
The following is a pseudo code snippet to explain the scenario.

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.class_name")))
......
driver.switch_to.default_content()
print('Switched back to default content')
# Error occurs when line below is interpreted
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[title^='Test %s']" %(array_of_content[1]))
```

Following error occurs:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/var/task/main.py", line 217, in test_method 
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[title^='Test %s']" %(array_of_content[1]))
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until 
 value = method(self._driver) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 213, in __call__ 
 element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 78, in __call__ 
 return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator)) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 307, in _find_element 
 return driver.find_element(*by) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element 
 'value': value})['value'] 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute 
 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute 
 return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data) 
 File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 471, in _request 
 resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open 
 response = self._open(req, data) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open 
 '_open', req) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain 
 result = func(*args) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1229, in http_open 
 return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1202, in do_open 
 r = h.getresponse(buffering=True) 
 File "/var/task/raven/breadcrumbs.py", line 328, in getresponse 
 rv = real_getresponse(self, *args, **kwargs) 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1132, in getresponse 
 response.begin() 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin 
 version, status, reason = self._read_status() 
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status 
 raise BadStatusLine(line) 
BadStatusLine: ''
```

Any ideas, what is happening.
As I am able to see the same error, even if I write `driver.save_screenshot('test.png')`.

But it is not throwing any error on local machines, also tried to use AMI instance to replicate if something is there in concern Amazon Linux.

Comment: Yep, I have the same issue... If you've found a solution please share